# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor que asume un nivel en una variable tipo factor?

Tags: r

Tengo un vector:

```
Genero <- factor(c("Femenino", "Masculino", "Otro"))
```

Quiero agregar un nuevo nivel "No corresponde" pero que no asuma el valor 4, quiero ponerle un valor específico, ejemplo 999 para poder usar siempre el mismo valor en todas la variables, sin importar la cantidad de niveles que tenga la variable tipo factor. Y que me permita rapidamente que corresponde a "No corresponde"; principalmente porque tengo que exportar esa base a otros formatos y donde el valor aparece.Esto es posible?

Answer (score 0):

No es posible manipular el `id` numérico de los `factores`, en todos los usos que R le da al dato `factor` se asumen cuestiones de orden entre cada categoría y de distancia entre estas, por lo cual es fundamental que exista coherencia en este dato. Podrías generar categorías `dummy` de la 4 a la 998, pero para R serían categorías adicionales que seguramente te complicarían el trabajo, si intentas luego eliminarlas con `droplevels()` te darás cuenta que el `id` de categoría se vuelve a reordenar y el `999 - No corresponde` pasaría a ser `4 - No corresponde`.

De todas formas, entiendo tu necesidad, y lo que podrías hacer es un vector de conversión para traducir la categoría 4 a la 999:

```
Genero
[1] Femenino       Masculino      Otro           No Corresponde
Levels: Femenino Masculino Otro No Corresponde

as.numeric(Genero)
[1] 1 2 3 4

c(1,2,3,999)[as.numeric(Genero)]
[1]   1   2   3 999
```